# Why do I get unresolved reference while the included file is there?

Tags: python, pycharm

Currently I'm working with multiple people on a python project. We are working with Github. I connected Git with Pycharm.

There is a main file and in that main file there are functions called from other files. The problem is that when

```
from LapentaEstimator import iterator
```

is called I get the error that it is a unresolved reference. I find that a bit strange since the LapentaEstimator file is uploaded to the file.

[image]

Exactly the same with Meshing, while the file is visible in the left.

Could somebody direct me in the right direction to tackle this problem?

Comment: Try: right click on `src`->Mark directory as -> Sources Root

Comment: This worked! Thanks